# Do not apply filter to column in case filter criteria does not exist

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following simple Excel sheet:

```
       A             B           C           D
1  Products        Check
2  Product A       OK
3  Product B       OK
4  Product C       OK
5  Product D       OK
6  Product E       OK
7
8
```

On this data I want to run a filter using this VBA:

```
Sub Filter()
Sheet1.Range("$A$1:$B$1").AutoFilter _
Field:=Sheet1.Range("$B$1").Column, _
Criteria1:="Error"
End Sub
```

This `VBA` works perfectly as long as the critiera `Error` appears at least once in `Column B`. 
However, as you can see in the example above the criteria `Error` does not appear at all. 
Now, when I run the `VBA` it kind of applies the filter to `Column B` and hides all the rows looking like this:

[image]

How, do I have to modify my `VBA` so in case the filter `criteria` does not exist in the `Column` the filter is not applied to it?

Comment: Multiple options. use `Range.Find` and check if not nothing. Or maybe a simple `WorksheetFunction.CountIf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, please:

```
Sub testFilterError()
  Dim strErr As String
  strErr = "Error"
   If Application.CountIf(Sheet1.Range("B1:B" & Sheet1.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row), "Error") > 0 Then
      Sheet1.Range("$A$1:$B$1").AutoFilter _
            field:=Sheet1.Range("$B$1").Column, _
                                Criteria1:=strErr
  Else
    MsgBox "No """ & strErr & """ string in B:B column..."
  End If
End Sub
```

The code can be easily adapted for some other words with strange behavior in filtering...

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I get run-time 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed on If Application.CountIf(Sheet1.Range("B1:B" & Sheet1.Range("B1").End(xlDown)), "Error") > 0

Comment: Refresh, please, the page and test it now. I missed `End(xlDown).Row`... I didn't test it. I thought it is simple to just write it...